# Xamarin - web service call works on simulator, not on iPhone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, monodevelop

I've never come across this, I have a web service call that's working on the iOS simulator just fine, but when I try to debug the same on my iPhone (7plus - 10.3.1), the application crashes and I get this very strange error. This is the call causing the the crash (I'm trying to format this as code, but it's not working at all):

```
var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
```

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(path, content, cancellationToken);

// CRASH OCCURS ON THE NEXT LINE

```
return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponse>(cancellationToken);
```

Here is the error:

System.ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method 'System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions:ReadAsAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpContent,System.Type,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1,System.Net.Http.Formatting.IFormatterLogger,System.Threading.CancellationToken)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

I don't appear to be doing anything that limitations link is describing and again it's working just fine on both the iOS simulator and Android simulator as well as my Android device. Any idea how to proceed? I can post more code if needed.

Comment: Do a `ReadAsStringAsync` and then deserialize it as your `TokenResponse` class

Comment: I'm sure I remember reading somewhere that passing a cancellation token to HttpClient causes problems, though for the life of me I cannot find it. Try taking the cancellation token out and see what happens.

Comment: So I was able to get it to work in iOS by using ReadAsStringAsync as SushiHanover suggested. However, now Android only is throwing "Method not allowed". Is that because I'm not passing the cancellation token anymore? I couldn't figure out how to pass the cancellation taken using ReadAsStringAsync.